# Сделать переменные видимыми js

Tags: javascript

Я хочу сделать функцию, которая принимает сколько угодно аргументов и делает их видимыми для всего кода. Приведу пример: на вход она принимает функцию `a` и в своём теле делает `window.a = a`, вся проблема заключается именно в том, что имена переменных нужно как-то получить. Конечно, можно собрать их все в объект и сделать видимым его, но хотелось бы именно сами переменные.

Вот моя функция (нерабочая):

```js
function MakeVisible () {
 for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
  window[arguments[i]] = arguments[i];
 };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мы можем узнать имя переменной если передавать их объектом, как-то так(не рекомендую использовать глобальные переменные в продакшене):

```js
function makeVisible (obj) {
 Object.keys(obj).map(item => window[item] = obj[item])
};

   var a = 1, b = 'string';
   makeVisible({a, b})
   // makeVisible({a:a, b:b}) без использования es6 синтаксиса 
   console.log(window.b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы изначально думали верно, но выбрали не тот вид `for`. Нужно использовать `for in`:

```js
function makeVisible(parameterObject)
{
 for(var i in parameterObject)
  window[i] = parameterObject[i]
}
//далее передаёте любое количество переменных, но в объекте:
makeVisible({first: 1, second: 2, third: 'третий'});
//после этого можете вызывать их даже без обращения через window – они будут видны везде.
console.log(first);
console.log(second);
console.log(third);
```